# How to allow both a user and root to access directory?

Tags: permissions, directory, root, users, groups

How can I make `/media/creeper39x/TB-Drive` be owned by creeper39x, but root have access?

Could I have a group with creeper39x and root in it??

Please help.

Comment: Please add some more to the question: the filesystem is important. If windows (ntfs etc) you set permissions during mounting and there are plenty of good examples on AU ;) Root always has access so I doubt there is a problem. Mind that we Ubuntu users do not use "root" but an admin with elevated privileges.